# Downloading a Video Clip referenced by a .swf file

Tags: firefox, video, flash

I bring up web page:
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152432831365653&set=vb.618775652&type=2&theater

This web page has a 'window' for playing a video clip. Using Firefox menu entry Tools->Page Info->Media, I see that the only entry for a .swf (or other video file) is:
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v1/y1/r/wp3fsUyK7CP.swf
with it shown as Embedded. Interestingly, this URL changes if I close Firefox & start again.

When I download this file (using the Save button) and open it, it just displays a blank page. This happens with any of VLC, Adobe Projector 16 or LightSpark. I've also tried the Firefox addon of Download Helper, but that didn't 'see' the video clip.

So my guess is that the .swf entry somehow refers to the real video file. How can I download the actual video clip as a file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a Firefox add-on like [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=userprofile), or any of the many other similar add-ons, to download any web video clips. Webpage designers don't generally want people to save their videos easily.